# How to get an even amount of grid cells

Tags: widget, google-app-maker

I am creating a library app and i am using the grid widget to display the books. At the bottom there is a singular grid cell. Is there a way to make it an even amount of cells in a row?[image]

Comment: The quantity of grid cells is directly dependent on the quantity of items in the datasource that is bound the grid widget. Therefore, this is not something that is easily changed unless you are using like a dynamic page property, set the property to an array of objects for example that are always length of 2. If you can provide additional info on your data binding for this grid widget, then we may be able to better assist you.

Comment: I have not added any binding for the grid yet. I only have binding for the image and labels within the grid. @MarkusMalessa